# How can I insert control character ^@ into a file using sed in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I am running below command on file `xyz`.

```
sed -i 's/abc \"/abc \^@\"/g' xyz
```

But I am not getting desired output.

If I manually typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> + <kbd>@</kbd> it is visible in vi editor as `^@` but not with above command output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The character you are referring to is a null byte (`0x00`). In sed you need to use `\x00` for it:

```
sed 's/abc \"/abc \x00\"/' file
```